# Limit number of text outputted using Meteor blaze

Tags: javascript, css, character, meteor-blaze, display

I have an app that accepts the 1000 minimum character as input, when I want to display it on the screen only about 400 characters should be displayed but I seem not to have found away of how to do this. This helper class returns an object, so via this all the variables can be accessed.

Template helper:

```
Template.SchoolDashboardLayout.helpers({
    selected: function () {
    return Session.equals('selectedSchool', this.__originalId) ? 'selected' : '';
}
})
```

This is the frontend using blaze which returns all the 1000 characters but I want to limit the display to only 400 characters, how can I do this?

```
<span> {{sellschoolvar}} </span>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could register another helper to truncate the string. If you register it as a global helper as below, you can use it elsewhere in your app (but you could just include it in the `SchoolDashboardLayout` helpers if you like).

```
Template.registerHelper("truncate", function(text) {
  return text.substring(0, 400)
});
```

And then your template would change to

```
<span>{{truncate sellschoolvar}}</span>
```

That's the basic idea - now you can play around with it to change the length of the truncated text, or add "..." to the end, or whatever you like.

See more about global template helpers [here](https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/using-global-template-helpers)